# Show if $S_1 \subseteq \text{span} S_2$ then span$(S_1) \subseteq $ span$(S_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vectors

I am proving this statement as an exercise, and wondering if my proof is correct or not. I am also wondering if there are any improvements that can be made to my writing style.

if $S_1 \subseteq \text{span} (S_2)$ then span$(S_1) \subseteq $ span$(S_2)$.

Edit: $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a finite dimensional vector space $V$

I have also assumed $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite, I'm not sure whether or not I was meant to do this though.

Proof:

let $S_1 = \{\textbf{v}_1,..,\textbf{v}_n\}$, $S_2 = \{\textbf{s}_1,...,\textbf{s}_j\}$. Suppose $S_1 \subseteq \text{span} (S_2)$.

let $\textbf{y} \in \text{span}(S_1)$. This implies that we can write $$\textbf{y} = \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + ... + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n$$ But we know that $\textbf{v}_1,...,\textbf{v}_n \in \text{span}(S_2)$ Hence, we can write $$\textbf{y} = \alpha_1(\lambda_{1,1} \textbf{s}_1 + ... + \lambda_{1,j} \textbf{s}_j) + ... + \alpha_n (\lambda_{n,1} \textbf{s}_1 + ... + \lambda_{n,j} s_j)$$ Where $\lambda_{i,k} \in \mathbb{F}, i \in \{1,..,n\}, k \in \{1,..,j\}$

This implies that $$\textbf{y} = (\alpha_1 \lambda_{1,1} \textbf{s}_1 + ... + \alpha_1 \lambda_{1,j} \textbf{s}_j) + ... + (\alpha_n \lambda_{n,1} \textbf{s}_1 + ... + \alpha_n \lambda_{n,j} \textbf{s}_j)$$ By the vector distributive law.

Simplifying, we get $$\textbf{y} = (\alpha_1 \lambda_{1,1} + ... + \alpha_n \lambda_{n,1}) \textbf{s}_1 + (\alpha_n \lambda_{1,j} + ... + \alpha_n \lambda_{n,j}) \textbf{s}_j$$ By using associativity and commutativity of vector addition, then the scalar distributive law.

We have written $\textbf{y}$ as a linear combination of vectors in $S_2$. Hence, $\textbf{y} \in \text{span}(S_2)$.

Hence, the result.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite?

Comment: Can you take it as a given that $\rm{span}(S_2)$ is a vector subspace by definition? Why not just show this for a general vector subspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I think the proof looks good. If you don't assume that $S_1$ and $S_2$ then your proof can be adapted.

One small suggestion: when you say that you can write $\textbf{y} = \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + ... + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n$, Say that there exists $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\Bbb{F}$ such that you can do this. Similar for the $\lambda_{i,j}$ (Here, you put that they are in $\Bbb{F}$, but say that they exist).

Comment: I am meant to assume that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a finite dimensional vector space, but I'm not sure about the sets being finite. How could I accommodate the sets being infinite?

Comment: Rather than finite sums and sequences of vectors/scalars, could I just replace them with infinite sums and sequences?

Comment: No, infinite sums are not defined in general for vector spaces. You actually still take finite sums. For example for **y**, you would say that there exists $v_1,\dots,v_n\in S_1$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in \Bbb{F}$ such that **y** $=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n$.

Comment: See this definition of span for dealing with the infinite case:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition